# How to search for all posts containing keyword using Sinatra and Datamapper?

Tags: html, ruby, forms, sinatra, datamapper

I am fairly new to full stack development and I am trying to get a simple search form to work. The webpage is supposed to redirect the user to a page with a list of all videos containing the keyword. Whenever I type in a title that exists, I get :NoMethodError at /posts/:title/search

I've tried using a query but have failed.

This is my app.rb. I query all videos that contain :title.

```
get "/posts/:title/search" do
    # authenticate!
    @results = Video.all(title: params[:title])

    if @results
        erb :search_success
    else
        flash[:error] = "Video not found."
        erb :search_success
    end

end
```

This is search_success.erb where I want to have a list of the videos that contains the keyword in the title.

```
<div class="container">
    <% @results.each do |r| %>
        <h1><%= r.title %></h1>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

This is navigation.erb where the search form lives.

```
<form action="/posts/:title/search" method="get">
        <input type="text" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: What does the NoMethodError say? What line is it coming from?

Comment: It's coming from line 2 in search_success.erb. Block in singleton class. <% @results.each do |r| %>

Comment: And what does the nomethoderror say? Undefined method each for nilclass?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible given the info you've shared. DataMapper's `all` method always returns an array, never nil. Please check again that your code and the error are exactly like you've shared. Also, you can save yourself hours of headache by using a debugger like pry. Put a breakpoint right before the line causing the error and see what's going on.

Comment: Is datamapper still an active project? It looks to me that last release was back in 2011? An alternative would be Sequel, very actively maintained, with excellent support from the author.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@results = Video.all(title: params[:title])
```

to

```
@results = Video.all(:title.like => "%#{params[:title])}%")
```

to get answers that don't need to match completely (i.e. match case etc.)

Also in your search form, you have two *type* attributes. You should change one of them to

```
name="title"
```